# CSS: background image as html code

Tags: html, css, background-image, font-awesome

I would like to know if it is possible to use pure `HTML` for the `background-image` property.

I have following case:

The original:

```
background-image:url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' version='1.1' height='16px' width='20px'><text x='0' y='15' fill='lightgray' font-family='sans-serif' font-size='20' font-weight='bold'>X</text></svg>") !important;
```

and I want something like this, because I am using a font for the images:

```
background-image:("<i class='icon icon-nein'></i>" !important);
```

Answer (score 3):

No, it isn't.

The background-image must be an image format supported by the browser.

SVG is an image format, HTML is not.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't use HTML as a background image. To achieve what you want you could used and absolutely positioned span.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the correct icon unicode, like this:

```
.element:before {
    content: "\f26c";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
}
```

Maybe it´s possible to use it as background, I haven't tested it.

You can find the codes right on the page of the icon.
Here a TV as example.

http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/television/